# How do I change text when click button ?

Tags: jquery

How do I change the text when click the button ?

When you see this DEMO here

```
 [https://jsfiddle.net/A8Znx/50/][1]
```

The texts change all together in same time.

How do I fix the jquery ? 
please help.

Comment: You are targeting all the <em>'s with $('.unit em').toggle(), you need to add some type of attribute that allows you to determine which <em> to toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your function to this:

```
$('.unit-toggler input').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('em').toggle();
});
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you using index() :

```
$('.unit-toggler').change(function() {
  var index = $(".unit-toggler").index($(this));
  $('.unit').eq(index).find('em').toggle();
});
```